# How to read STDIO stream in PHP

Tags: php, stream, stdio

I need to read a input stream through PHP.

**Response OBJECT:**

```
Serial Object
(
    [_device] => \.\com4
    [_windevice] => COM4
    [_dHandle] => Resource id #23
    [_dState] => 2
    [_buffer] => 
    [_os] => windows
    [autoflush] => 1
)
```

I need to extract information from **[_dHandle] => Resource id #23**. I've extract metadata

```
stream_get_meta_data($serial->_dHandle)
```

and found following:

```
Array
(
    [wrapper_type] => plainfile
    [stream_type] => STDIO
    [mode] => r+b
    [unread_bytes] => 0
    [seekable] => 1
    [uri] => \.\com4
    [timed_out] => 
    [blocked] => 1
    [eof] => 
)
```

Please suggest me how I can extract data from that Resource Id: #23

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what kind of resource it is. You can use function

[get_resource_type()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-resource-type.php) on _dHandle and then depends on type of resource use proper function to read it.

If it is a stream then you can use fopen, fread etc, if it is mysql then use mysql function, if it is xml then use xml read functions etc.

Change your code from

This is bad code change

```
$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');
$res = stream_get_contents($stdin, -1, 10);`
```

to

```
$stream = fopen($serial->_dHandle, 'r');
echo stream_get_contents($stream, -1, 10);
fclose($stream);
```

If $stream is false then it cannot be opened, if it has pointer then it means that connection is open. Then if stream_get_contents() returns no data it means it is not available or haven't been sent yet.

Comment: get_resource_type returns with **stream**. I tried fopen(), it returns "failed to open stream". and fread() goes for unlimited loading.

Comment: so it means that resource is broken and you won't be able to open it. You could also try http://php.net/manual/en/streamwrapper.stream-open.php but rather it won't change anything. Is it socket stream?

Comment: with php you can also access streams via `$stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'r');`

Comment: Thanks @Robert for your time. I am really stack here. with php://stdin, now its showing: **resource(24) of type (stream)**.

Comment: because when you fopen you need to read it with some read function like fread or stream_get_contents($handle, -1, 10);  and then fclose($handle);

Comment: I tried everything. **stream_get_contents()** returns string(0) "". I am confused that whether that resource contains any data or not. Am I trying to read an empty stream? I don't know. could you please take a look ate the code: [Here](http://pastebin.com/rPLDB1R0)

Comment: When I try to **fopen($serial->_dHandle, 'r');**, it shows, fopen() expects parameter 1 to be a valid path, resource given